# Rsync to stdout?

Tags: linux, shell, rsync, tar, pipe

I have access to backup server via rsync protocol (only rsync, nothing else). Now, I want to fetch file from there (which is .tar.gz) and pass it directly to tar command, without saving the archive in local filesystem.

To visualize, with ssh access I could:

```
ssh remote_host cat backup.file.tar.gz | tar xzf -
```

And I will get uncompressed backup locally, without actually storing .tar.gz on local machine.

Is it possible to achieve when using rsync?

Answer (score 6):

Normally you could just use a named pipe, like so:

```
mkfifo mypipe
tar xzf mypipe &
rsync --inplace server:/remote/file.tar.gz mypipe
```

However, rsync is too smart for it's own good, since it recognizes that the remote file is a normal file and the local one is a pipe.  So it first deletes the pipe, then transfers the remote file.  `scp` doesn't have this problem, and will happily send the data into the named pipe (unfortunately that doesn't help you here).

Comment: Answer checkmark. @user7385

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you might be able to use `scp`:

```
scp file /dev/stdout
```

will copy the file to standard output. You can add the necessary remote user and host information for the source of the file to the command line arguments of `scp`.

Comment: As I mentioned: I don't have ssh/scp. Just rsync access.

Comment: @depesz: Sorry, I don't see where you mentioned that.

Comment: "I have access to backup server via rsync protocol." I didn't mention access by ssh because i don't have it. I also didn't mention other protocols - I just have rsync.

Comment: And even if it does not work:
`scp: local ftruncate "/dev/stdout": Invalid argument
scp: write local "/dev/stdout": Illegal seek`

Answer (score 0):

to make it short: you can't. rsync works by talking between 2 instances of rsync (client- and server side), to find out the differences. tar is not able to speak 'rsyncish'.

Comment: but one of the clients could (theoretically) write somehow to pipe instead of file.

Comment: The rsync protocol requires bi-directional communication - full duplex on a single channel. This is not possible with pipes, they are simplex only. All rsync ever sends to stdout is status information.

Comment: Not sure what rsync protocol has to do with output. I am not talking about replacing rsync with tar. I am talking about making rsync client write file (for example downloaded with --whole-file option, to prevent seeks and checksum checks) to pipe, not to file.